# bluetooth not working in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth

rfkill status:

```
ID TYPE         DEVICE             SOFT         HARD
 0 wlan          hp-wifi              unblocked  unblocked
 1 bluetooth   hp-bluetooth     unblocked  unblocked
 2 wlan          phy0                unblocked   unblocked
```

sudo dmesg | grep -i blue status

```
[   18.449774] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   18.449804] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   18.449807] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   18.449812] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   18.449815] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.449822] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   21.210206] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   21.210216] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   21.210219] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[   21.210268] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[   21.210272] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[   21.210316] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   21.210382] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[   21.210482] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   21.210577] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[   21.210583] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[   21.210618] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[   65.318242] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   65.318253] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   65.318258] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service status:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-06-09 01:41:44 IST; 1 day 18h ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1106 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4546)
     Memory: 1.0M
        CPU: 135ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1106 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

'bluetoothctl show' shows

```
No default controller available
```

'lsmod | grep btusb' shows

```
btusb                  61440  0
btrtl                  24576  2 hci_uart,btusb
btbcm                  24576  2 hci_uart,btusb
btintel                40960  2 hci_uart,btusb
bluetooth             688128  13 btrtl,btqca,btintel,hci_uart,btbcm,bnep,btusb
```

'sudo modprobe -v btusb' shows

```
insmod /lib/modules/5.15.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko
```

Comment: `bluetoothctl show`? `lsmod | grep btusb`? `sudo modprobe -v btusb`

Comment: @PabloBianchi i have added the results

Comment: Did you run the first command **after** loading kernel module with modprobe?

Comment: yes i think i did that

Comment: It sure would be nice if someone would actually follow up on their bluetooth issues...